# Variable scope of webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension. It places overlays on YouTube videos and give them a number.

manifest.josn

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "overlay",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Place overlay on Youtube Videos",

"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
       "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png" },

"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
}


]

}
```

content.js:

```
    function assign() {
var x = [];
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if(x[i].lastChild.className != "overlay"){
                overlay = document.createElement("div");
            overlay.className = "overlay";
            overlay.style.opacity = 0.9;
            overlay.style.background = "red";
            overlay.style.top =0;
            overlay.style.bottom =0;
            overlay.style.left =0;
            overlay.style.right =0;
            overlay.style.position = "absolute";
            overlay.innerText = i;
            x[i].appendChild(overlay);
            x[i].style.position = "relative";
            }
        }
    console.log(x[3]);
    console.log('Standby!');
    }

    function toggle() {
        overlays = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay"); 
        for (overlay in overlays) {
            if(overlays[overlay].style.opacity == 0.9){
                overlays[overlay].style.opacity = 0;
            }else{overlays[overlay].style.opacity = 0.9;}
        }
    }

            window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 116){toggle();
                        }else if (e.keyCode == 114){
                        assign();
                        }
    });
```

(There are many irrelevant stuff there but I don't want people to blame me for posting part of the code)

The problem is, the x[] array update properly every time I call the assign() function.

As a result, even if you click on a link on the webpage then call assign() again, x[3] on the console always is the same element. But I don't think this is supposed to happen, because every time I called assign() function, x[] array should get cleared right on the first line of code.

The only way the x[] array will clear properly is hitting F5. How to clear the x[] array properly without F5?

Comment: `var x = []; `<-- that means nothing when you override it on the next line.

Comment: well sounds like getElementsByClassName is always returning the same thing. Add some debugging and find out what is going on.

Comment: Doesn't the function reads from top to bottom? i.e. clear x[] then assign it with new things

Comment: The code is no different than just doing `var x = document.get....` and it will be new each time. Issue looks like you never remove the things you created from the first time. Do you remove the DOM elements? I do not see that anywhere.

Comment: I never remove what? Sorry I can't see it...

Comment: I thought I remove the elements by the first line of code. Apparent it does not. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: That array has nothing to do with the elements you append to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

> As a result, even if you click on a link on the webpage then call assign() again, x[3] on the console always is the same element

What @epascarello is saying is that when you call assign the logic in your code will always populate element x[3]. So how's it going to be empty after you call assign?

If you want to clear the array after your call to assign() then you could do that after your for loop ends.

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding you. I don't need to array to be empty, I just need it to be updated when the webpage reloaded. What I always believe is that if you fire the code "x = document.getElementsByClassName", the x[] array should be different if your page url chages and you fire "x = document.getElementsByClassName" again, but it is not the case. The array is always the same. The only way is if you go to another url + F5, then x[] array will be different when you  fire "x = document.getElementsByClassName"

Comment: I have been doing tests for some time. Seems like the return of "document.getElementsByClassName" doesn't change on url changes. It only change on F5. Which is annoying.

Comment: I said the word "clear the array" because I thought I should empty the array and then it fill it with new stuff in order to update the array. But turns out the even got the syntax wrong.

Comment: No actually the x[] array get updates, but the old return results won't go away. The new array will be old results on top and new results afterwards. Which is still annoying. Might be a YouTube thing, I did test on google search result it works fine.

Comment: I understand now. I would expect var x to be cleared because its scoped to the function assign() but that's not what you're seeing. Sorry can't help you with this.